# file upload with php

Tags: php, file, file-upload

Hi every body I am uploading file with php
every thing is fine but move_uploded_file is not working
every variable displayed record and all permission for file is set

```
function uploadfile($filename)
{



    $filetype=$filename["type"];
    $filename=$filename['name']; 
    $filetempname=$filename['tmp_name'];
    if($filetype=="application/msword")
    {
        move_uploaded_file($filetempname,"resume/".$filename);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what happens, what error messages come up and what `$filetempname` contains.

Comment: Just a wild guess: the folder `resume` exists yes? But you specify a relative path, so does the folder exists where the script is executed?

Answer (score 5):

The `$filename` array, turns into a string at this line: `$filename=$filename['name'];`

I'm wondering why you didn't get an error message.

Try an other var name instead of $filename as a function parameter and i'm sure it will work!

Comment: +1 Nice catch. Technically its a warning and he/she has those turned off. Probably.

Answer (score 1):

First of all set error reporting on, on top of your script put this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then make sure that file type is really `application/msword`

```
echo $filetype;
```

And make sure that the path is correct:

```
echo "resume/".$filename;
```

Also make sure that:

- Directory has write permissions
- You are specifying the correct path
- Try your path like `"./resume/".$filename`
- Try prefixing your path with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($filetype=="application/msword")
```

That line won't work, because it is almost guaranteed the browser won't try to detect the file mime type. Take the `if` statement out and it should work.

You should still try to validate the file in a different way (and absolutely make sure it is not PHP, cause that would be a huge security vulnerability).

Comment: Then you will need to give about 5000 times more detail. Turn on error reporting?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting display_errors = on, then you'll get error messages ;-) Or output some message in the else statement to see wether the if-condition didn't match.

Answer (score 0):

the first element you have to check when doing upload is $filename["**error**"]